# Исключение вложенных папок GIT

Tags: git

Имеется такая файловая структура:

```
-root
| .git
| .gitignore
| root-file.txt
| -home
  | .gitkeep
  | home-file.txt
```

содержимое файла `.gitignore`:

```
/home/*
!/home/
!/home/.gitkeep
```

Команда [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046563/ignore-git-in-parent-directories-for-git-status-branch-etc) `C:\root> git status`:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   ../.gitignore
        new file:   ../.root_file
        new file:   .gitkeep
```

Команда [2]  `C:\root\home> git status` выводит соответственно тоже самое.

Как настроить репозиторий или сам git что бы при нахождении в папке `home` git "не видел репозиторий"?

вот так сделать: `C:\root\home> git status`

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Возможно ли это?

---

Нашёл ответ тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046563/ignore-git-in-parent-directories-for-git-status-branch-etc. Можно ли это сделать на винде и для каждого отдельного репозитория

Comment: `.gitignore` используется самим гитом для игнорирования тех файлов, что не нужно добавлять в индекс, не думаю, он вам поможет :)

Comment: Структура репозитория должна быть с папкой ‘home’, в ней вместо .gitignore папка .vscode с настройками будет, а вот остальное не нужно

Comment: `.gitignore` не обязательный, но его `.vscode` не заменит

Comment: Ой ошибочка .gitkeep имел ввиду )

Comment: `.gitkeep`, судя по ответу https://stackoverflow.com/a/7229996/5909792 не аналог `.gitignore` и не является документированной вещью, его используют для добавления в репозиторий пустых папок (папок, в которые помещается `.gitkeep`, но этим может быть любой другой файл, например какой-нибудь `README`)

Comment: @gil9red именно, в репозитории должна быть папка home, при открытии ее из консоли git не должен понимать что она часть репозитория

Comment: Похоже на очередную X-Y проблему. Зачем вам это нужно? Какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Задача: в проекте vscode есть рабочие области со своими настройками которые все хранятся в папке root, папки рабочих областей это home-1, home-2 и тд. задача в том что бы когда я открывал папку рабочей области она не знала что находиться в репозитории.

Comment: @AlexeyTen это мне нужно что бы для каждой рабочей области (home) мог выполнить команду git init, а так как все папке root все кроме настроек в игноре он не узнает что там другой репозиторий

Comment: зачем вам репозиторий в root? удалите и сделайте отдельный реп на каждую рабочую область

Comment: что бы хранить в нем настройки vscode  и если я их поменяю то в каком нибудь старом проекте мог их просто спулить

Comment: Как вариант добавляйте каждый независимый репозиторий (home1, home2 и т.д.) как submodule в `root`. Тогда они будут жить независимой жизнью, но при этом будут как подпапки в root. Второй вариант, это добавить home1, home2 в .gitignore в root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Нашёл ответ тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046563/ignore-git-in-parent-directories-for-git-status-branch-etc. Можно ли это сделать на винде и для каждого отдельного репозитория

Да, можно.

Нужно любым способом установить переменную окружения `GIT_CEILING_DIRECTORIES` равной списку путей, по аналогии с переменной среды `PATH`. В ответе по ссылке разделитель двоеточие, как принято в unix, в windows — точка с запятой (`;`).

Важно, что поиск папки `.git` будет игнорироваться не для указанной папки, а для всех её подпапок.

То есть, если вы выполните в виндовой консоли

```
SET GIT_CEILING_DIRECTORIES=C:\root\home\
```

то в самой папке `home` status будет работать как и сейчас, а в подпапках проектов уже выведет, что это не репозиторий.

Если же сделать

```
SET GIT_CEILING_DIRECTORIES=C:\root\
```

То получите как и написано в вопросе. Но при этом и во всех соседних с home подпарках git будет уверен, что вы не в репозитории.